# Does the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\cos(\frac{1}{n+1})-\cos(\frac{1}{n})]$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do these series converge or diverge? What test would you use to show this? Find the sum of the series when possible.

I am stuck with this one and I don't know how to go about it.

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[\cos\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]$$

Comment: The partial sums are telescoping.

Comment: To the OP. Don't forget the this telescoping series has an infinite term that does not go to zero....it contributes to your sum....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N[\cos(\frac1{n+1})-\cos(\frac1n)]=[\cos(\frac12)-\cos(1)]+[\cos(\frac13)-\cos(\frac12)]+...+[\cos(\frac1{N})-\cos(\frac1{N-1})]+[\cos(\frac1{N+1})-\cos(\frac1N)]=-\cos(1)+\cos(\frac1{N+1})$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty[\cos(\frac1{n+1})-\cos(\frac1n)]=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-\cos(1)+\cos(\frac1{n+1}))=-\cos(1)+\cos(0)=1-\cos(1)=0.46$$

Comment: Well it's not equal to .46

Comment: Approximately 0.46.....................